# How to get 12 hour format time string when system is set to use 24 hour format

Tags: ios, datetime, locale

I want to get a time string like "10:00 PM", and I use the NSDateFormatterShortStyle to achieve this.
However when the system is set to use 24-hour format, what I got is "22:00".

Besides, I want to get a localized time string. For example, in Chinese, I want to get "下午10:00" instead of "10:00 PM". So I have to use the [NSLocale currentLocale], and can't use the en_US_POSIX locale.

Please help me to get a localized 12-hour format time string.

I need not only the hour part, and also the am/pm part. Besides, am/pm part may locate before the hour/minute part or after the hour/minute part depending on locale. Just like the system display time.
When system is set to use 12-hour format, it's just simple. But when the system is using 24-hour format, I just can't get the localized 12-hour format time string.

Comment: Why would you do that to your app user?

Comment: guys I gave an answer here, plz see this:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/50679548/9863222

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well this should work:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:[NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"hh:mm a" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]];
NSString *theTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

This should get you a date formatter that will give the date in 12 hour format. The lower case hh indicates hours 1-12 format. See the Unicode Technical Standard #35 section of [Date Format Patterns](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for details on the format string.

Unfortunately iOS will rewrite the format string based on the user's 24-hour format preference setting. I can find no way around that setting using Cocoa's date formatting. Since the 24-hour format will drop the am/pm designation, parsing the resulting string to convert hours greater than 12 will result in ambiguous time strings. Therefore the only remaining options I can see is honoring the users 24-hour preference setting or using other localization code. You can write your own, or maybe find an open source replacement.

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't work. dateFormatFromTemplate:option:locale: returns a time format string, not a NSDateFormatter object.

Comment: My original answer was wrong, so I heavily edited the answer.

Comment: Its worked for me thanks.. It gives me "11:00 PM" format.. I want like 11pm... so I tried with hha but it still gives 11 PM.. how to get it like "11pm" ?

Comment: @iphonegeek You can post process the string using NSString methods like lowercaseString and stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:.

Comment: @Mr.Berna: Ok. Thanks. I thought there might be way to do it in dateformatter itself.. anyways thanks for your quick reply. I think this will work for me.

Comment: When I format it with "hh:mm" I get 01:35. Is there anyway to get 1:35?

Comment: This is still the case as of iOS 9. From what I can tell, every locale has a default hour format (en_US is 12-hour). If the user changes the switch in settings so the format doesn't match the default (use 24-hour), the app will always show that new setting unless you manually change the locale on the date formatter.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.0**

```
    var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: "hh:mm a", options: 0, locale: NSLocale.current)
    var theTime: String = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
```

Answer (score -3):

```
NSInteger originalHour = hour;
BOOL isPm = YES;
if (hour >= 12) {
    if (hour > 12)
        hour -= 12;
}
else {
    isPm = NO;
}

if (hour == 0)
    hour = 12;
```