# How to get current time in 12 hour format?

Tags: ios, swift, date

I want get current time in 12 hour format.I want format if time is 18:36 then it should be like 06:35 PM. for this purpose i have used below code but it just don't give me required format.I get format like this.

```
let date = Date()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
let date22 = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
```

Comment: Also, this site is a great thing for figuring out what you need : http://nsdateformatter.com/

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the original time input? A `String` or a `Date`?

Answer (score 5):

Check out this date formatting [guide](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime). & this [site](http://nsdateformatter.com).

```
let dateAsString = "6:35 PM"
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateAsString)

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
let date24 = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date!)
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that the OP want's the hour format with a leading 0 and this answer (whilst totally correct) would not include the leading 0. Simple fix though, just a case of adding a second "h" so the format string would be "hh:mm a".

Answer (score 2):

swift 2:

```swift
let date = NSDate() // return current time and date
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a" // for specifying the change to format hour:minute am/pm.
let dateInString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date) // provide current time in string formatted in 06:35 PM if current time is 18:35

print(dateInString)
```

swift 4:

```swift
let date = NSDate()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
let dateInString = dateFormatter.string(from: date as Date)
```

in your code

Comment: FYI - to use Swift 3, `NSDate` needs to be `Date` and `NSDateFormatter` needs to be `DateFormatter`. And the format does not change between versions of Swift.

Comment: Please suggest with your code i am able to get time as 18:36 but not as 06:36 PM

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem(from my backend dateString is coming in 24 hours format and also in UTC), so I created a function it is working perfectly. See this function:-

```
func getRequiredFormat(dateStrInTwentyFourHourFomat: String) -> String? {

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

    if let newDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateStrInTwentyFourHourFomat) {

        let timeFormat = DateFormatter()
        timeFormat.timeZone = TimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent
        timeFormat.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        timeFormat.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"

        let requiredStr = timeFormat.string(from: newDate)
        return requiredStr
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```