# Swift how to get 12 hours format if system is 24 hour format

Tags: ios, swift

My iPhone device system was set in 24hours format i want to get 12 hours format, that is:         **23:27** get **11:27 PM**.

I tried:

```
            let today = NSDate()
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
            let string = dateFormatter.string(from: today as Date) // 23:27
```

got `23:27` string.

I found this: [How to get 12 hour format time string when system is set to use 24 hour format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247790/how-to-get-12-hour-format-time-string-when-system-is-set-to-use-24-hour-format)

```
            let today = NSDate()
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            let dateFormat = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate:"hh:mm a", options: 0, locale: NSLocale.current)
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormat
            let string = dateFormatter.string(from: today as Date) //23:27 i want 11:27 pm
```

But it doesn't work i still got `23:27` string not `11:27pm` string.

Thanks!

**EDIT**:
According to `shallowThought`'s answer not sure if `Locale` is the case?

[image]

**EDIT2**
Add this:

```
dateFormatter1.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```

works. And my current locale is `en_CN`.

Comment: I've ran your code and have `9:34 PM` in `string` variable

Comment: @ArtemNovichkov see my screenshot.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this link solves your issue. If not, please edit your question with why it doesn't help, we might reopen the question if necessary. Thanks.

Comment: Another good one is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613110/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-the-nsdateformatter-locale-feature?s=2|0.0000

Answer (score 4):

Your code works fine here on an iPhone6, iOS 10.1.1 with date set to 24 hours:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let today = NSDate()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
    let string = dateFormatter.string(from: today as Date)
    print(string)
}
```

Prints:

```
04:38 PM
```

Comment: See my attached image. It's wired.

Comment: Post more info. iOS version aso.

Comment: its not working for me

Comment: @PatelJigar Check the locale of your device.